# How CakePhp 2.5 receive data post from Android?

Tags: android, cakephp, post

I want to know how CakePhp 2.5 receive data post from Android

I want to know the following

**1.URL to be sent from Android application**

**2.Methods of receiving data is POST (CakePhp)**

I have tried many times,but I couldn't it.

Sending the data from the Android is neatly confirmed

1
Now I wrote the following URL.I don't know it is right.

http://*********/cake/books/test

2
BooksController.php

```
<?php
        class BooksController extends AppController
        {
            public $name = 'Books';
            public $uses  = array('Book');

            public function test()
            {
                $add = "";
                if( isset($this->request->data['id']))
                {
                    $add = $this->request->data['id'];
                    $this->set( 'address' , $add);  
                }
            }       
        }
?>
```

test.ctp

```
<div>
<?php 
    if( isset($address) )
    {
        pr($address);           
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: tigrang,thank you!!

There are no errors.Both Android and CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP you can use the following function to test is it is a POST request:

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on the setup of your Webserver and CakePHP, the URL to post could also be:

http://*****/books/test (without the cake part)

Comment: Anton74,Thank you.

The problem has been solved.
The original purpose was to put a variable to the database.
Then I could do it using your advice code.
I do not know why can't echo a value receive from Android.

Answer (score 0):

just order Android to post a URL example

> www.sample.com/controller_name/function_name/123

, 123 is your code or variable

You can then use as simple function parameter

```
 //in your controller 
function register($uuid=null)
{
  echo $uuid; //$uuid is value post by android, register() is function name
}
```

Comment: Wayne Tun,thank you
The problem has been solved.
The original purpose was to put a variable to the database.
Then I could do it.
But I couldn't do it using your advice code.
And I do not know why can't echo a value receive from Android.